# Why regex [a-z]* does not mach anything in the string `The`?

Tags: regex

This might seem like a basic stuff but I cannot get my head around it.

String : `The`

Why regex `[a-z]+` matches `he` but regex `[a-z]*` does not match anything at all? The way I see it is since quantifier `*` matches zero or more times it should match the same as `+` did in the previous example namely `he`. How come quantifier `+` was able to process the string after the capital "T" but quantifier `*` was not?

EDIT:
In regards to Regex tools I simply used online resources found at:
http://regexr.com/ and https://regex101.com/

Comment: My guess: `[a-z]*` has two matches: empty string before `T`, and the rest, `he`. You only see the first match.

Comment: @tobias_k Yep, you can see the empty match before the `T` (indicated with vertical line) [here](https://regex101.com/r/qR9tI6/1).

Comment: In Java, use `while` with `matcher.find()` to get all matches. A rule of thumb is to avoid using unanchored patterns that may match empty strings.

Comment: BTW -- `[a-z]` is bad practice; use `[[:lower:]]` instead; your users in non-English-speaking locales (where the former can be buggy) will thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Difficult to tell from you question, but my guess is: `[a-z]*` has *multiple* matches: an empty string before `T`, and the rest, i.e. `he`. You probably only see the first match.

With `[a-z]+`, the first (and only) match is `he`.

Depending on the language/tool you use, there may be different functions for getting just the first match, or for getting all the matches. Here's an example in Python:

```
>>> re.search("[a-z]*", "The").group()
''
>>> re.findall("[a-z]*", "The")
['', 'he', '']
```

Comment: This is correct. But since we don't know what language or tool the OP is using, it may also be helpful to point out that in some languages and tools like JavaScript, you must pass a global flag to discover multiple matches. For example: `'The'.match(/[a-z]*/)` returns `[""]`, while `'The'.match(/[a-z]*/g)` returns `["", "he", ""]`.

Comment: @gfullam I think that's already covered by _"Depending on the language/tool you use, there may be different functions for getting just the first match, or for getting all the matches."_

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes it is, I just thought it worth sharing another example from a commonly used language.

Comment: @gfullam, thank you for introducing me to 'g' flag. It was indeed the case that there was multiple matches and the first one was an empty string.